# Using experimentalSourceRewriting in cypress

Tags: cypress, end-to-end

Is it possible to use `experimentalSourceRewriting` in a cypress test file and not to use it in the `cypress.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

This configuration option `experimentalSourceRewriting` cannot be set directly in a test.
See https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Test-Configuration